# Non-exported variable still available to code running in top-level JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've got a very basic HTML file, index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="bar">baz</h1>
    <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which, as you can see, contains a top level module, main.js:

```
import { setupWord, isLetterInWord } from './word.js'

const theWord = 'apple'

setupWord(theWord)

document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', () => {
    //do a "coin flip" every time this function is run to see if the letter is a or b
    let letter = Math.random() >= .5 ? 'a' : 'b'
    console.log('the letter is: ' + letter, '...is this letter in "apple"?')
    console.log(isLetterInWord(letter))
})
```

which has a single imported module, word.js:

```
let word;

export function setupWord(initWord) {
    word = initWord;
}

export function isLetterInWord(letter) {
    return word.includes(letter);
}
```

The thing I don't understand about this code is the `word` variable in `word.js`. What is it's scope at runtime? I don't export it as I do the two functions that reference it. I was under the impression that once I export my two functions to `main.js`, they live and breathe in the same context as everything else in `main.js`, and everything I don't export from `word.js` gets discarded. However, this is obviously not the case, as I can modify the `word` variable from `main.js` via `setupWord`, and then reference it again in another function's (`isLetterInWord`) scope context, also in `main.js`.

Why is it that invoking `isLetterInWord` doesn't throw a `cannot read properties of undefined` error? Is there a term for this type of behavior in JS?

Comment: "*once I export my two functions to main.js, they live and breathe in the same context as everything else in main.js*" - nope. You get nothing but a **reference** to them, their scope does not change. They're normal closures over the module scope. If you did `import` them in *multiple* modules, you'd still get the same functions everywhere, not a new function with a different context every time you import it somewhere.